# publish application created with animate cc fails

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, jquery-animate, adobe, publish

i try to publish my app on iPad and iPhone x.
the publish on iPad works OK however the publishing on the iPhone get error.
tried to reset the device in certificates identifiers and profiled but no help.
i understand it is impossible to remove the device and reinstall again,
very important -**i used  this device in past for other apps and it worked perfectly[ente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3uri.png)**r image description here.

Comment: Could you detail the steps you've taken to publish on the iPhone, and the precise error you're getting?

Comment: i created an app using animate cc.

Comment: created an app using animate cc. tried to install it on my two devices. iPhone and iPad.(as i did successfully did in past).( i have only two assigned devices. ). the publish on my iPad succeeded but  the publish on iPhone failed. "the device has encountered an unexpected error. error connecting to your device." i say again- i used this device successfully only few weeks ago.